# How to stop ion-text-nowrap break ion-grid inside ion-card

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ion-grid

I have a grid that has one row, and use ngFor to loop multiple column for each cell. Inside each cell first row will be ion-item wrap a thumbnail and the label. Below there are 1 row with 2 col.
Example code.

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>      
      <ion-text color="primary"><h1>Title</h1></ion-text>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col *ngFor="let s of sList">
        <ion-card>
          <ion-row>
            <ion-item>
              <!--  picture -->
              <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
                <img alt="Silhouette of mountains" src="https://ionicframework.com/docs/demos/api/thumbnail/thumbnail.svg" />
              </ion-thumbnail>
              <ion-label>id : </ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-row>
          <ion-row >
            <ion-col >         
                <div class="ion-text-nowrap">This is content left</div>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col >            
                <div class="ion-text-nowrap">This is content right</div>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
 </ion-grid>
```

My problem is on desktop mode(1440x1062), after adding the ion-text-nowrap attribute the column explanded to whole row and forced the another column inside the row wrap below like this .

[image]

But what I want to achieve is something like this, and the code above works but only in mobile range,

[image]

once it gets to tablet range(768px) the problem mentioned above appeared.

How can make sure the text-no-wrap won't effects the tablet view and making sure those 2 column stay shoulder to shoulder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer now, It has to do with setting the col size. For some reason, ion-col size attribute auto is different from not setting one. The difference seems to be :

set size auto -

- set a same dynamic size for each col

not setting a size auto -

- set different dynamic size for different col

so the code will be like this :

```
<ion-col size="auto" *ngFor="let s of sList">
    <ion-card >
        <ion-row>
            <ion-item>
              <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
                <img alt="Silhouette of mountains" src="https://ionicframework.com/docs/demos/api/thumbnail/thumbnail.svg" />
              </ion-thumbnail>
              <ion-label>label</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-row>
          Small title --
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col><div class="ion-text-nowrap">a__item : xxxx</div></ion-col>
            <ion-col><div class="ion-text-nowrap">b____item xxxx</div></ion-col>
          </ion-row>
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col><div class="ion-text-nowrap">a__item : xxxx</div></ion-col>
            <ion-col><div class="ion-text-nowrap">b____item xxxx</div></ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-card>
</ion-col>
```

Now the col won't expand whole row, each col has same size. And the text won't auto wrap.